# Is it possible to have different line scalemode options for parent and child display objects?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Imagine situation when child component is scaled and parent component is scaled as well. I want line to be drawn without scaling in child component and to  be scaled in parent. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks, Aleksey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. A child will always scale with its parent and they can not have independent scale modes.